# Regenerating resolv.conf

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I managed to stomp on my /etc/resolv.conf file. I believe this is the cause of me getting

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

It says resolv.conf is auto generated but I cannot figure out how to regenerate this file back to its previous default settings. I've checked many forums and the man files and I am stuck.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolv.conf file is, in case of ubuntu, generated by the NetworkManager. Disabling the adapter and re-enabling it afterwards should refresh the resolv.conf as NetworkManager fetches the informations via DHCP.

However, this is question is not suited for stackoverflow, as it has nothing to do with programming or some software framework or the like. You might have gone to the ubuntu stack exchange thingy: https://askubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You could reinstall resolvconf to restore the default configuration:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf
```

Another idea would be remove "resolvconf" and then install:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```